# Ubuntu 10.04 RAID 10 rebuild status

Tags: ubuntu, raid5

I got an IBM x3550 M3 server, with 6x 300GB SAS HDD installed, running in RAID10. Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS is installed. For RAID card, I'm using ServeRAID M5014.

If a HDD is replaced, how can I know the RAID rebuild status?

Comment: For software RAID, you can check the status with `cat /proc/mdstat/`. I don't know if that will work for hardware raid cards though.

Answer (score 0):

i forgot if it's working or not on your case, but i ever use it (using different raid card).
use MegaCLI util to show your raid status http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5073015

how to use megacli http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/systems/support/system_x_pdf/ibm_doc_sraidmr_megacli-1stedition_userguide.pdf

Comment: MegaCLI is RedHat only. Any solution suitable for Ubuntu ?

Comment: i see, it's rpm. may be you try using alien to convert rpm to deb ? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux/. or use this http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/DebianPackages hope that all work

Comment: I used `alien` to convert to `deb`, but errors occurred. See: http://pastebin.com/saTCZkhM

Comment: how about  hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/DebianPackages  ?, it's debian package and seem support for megacli.

Comment: test in progress. will update very soon.